# how to sum values in a table with multiple criterias

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables

I need your help with an excel formula. I want to sum values of a table based on criterias in the first row and the first column

[image: as shown in this image]

**e.g. row-criteria="z" and column-criteria="1": for those criterias the solution is 3.69 (1.06+1.38+1.25=3.69)**

SUMPRODUCT does not work for me.

Comment: Can't see what columns those are, but: `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$5:$A$9="z")*($B$4:$G$4=1)*$B$5:$G$9)` should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Rory's comment is optimal, though you may want step by step results.
Then, you have to use additional columns (eg. AA-AC) to compute each intermediary result:

AA4: `1`
AB4: `2`
AC4: `3`
AA5: `=sum.if($B9:$G9,$4:$4)`

AA6-AA9 and AB5-AC9: same formula extended from AA5

AA10: `=sum(AA$5:AA$9)`

AB10-AC10: same formula extended from AA10

Your end result wil be computed in AD10 `=sum(AA10:AC10)` as sums of cases of 1's, 2's and 3's.

Dollar symbols are used to have formula be extended and valid on nearby cells.

Where a single value is expected, `$4:$4` is the same as `<Current Column>$4`. Same goes for columns.